# Index on integer column not helping. Help? (EXPLAIN ANALYZE output inside)

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning

The table `market_trades` has an integer column `market_id` which takes values from 1 to 5. This seems like a pretty straightforward query to get the number of trades on each market:

```
WITH markets AS (
    SELECT unnest('{1,2,4}'::int[]) AS market_id
)
SELECT m.market_id, count(td.id) AS agg
FROM markets m
LEFT JOIN market_trades td
ON td.market_id = m.market_id
GROUP  BY m.market_id
ORDER  BY m.market_id;
```

But it takes about 10 full seconds to run! I added an index on `market_trades.market_id`, but it did not speed up the query at all.

The `market_trades` table has about 30 million rows.

Here is the ouput of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the above query ([on depesz](http://explain.depesz.com/s/EQYP)):

```
                                                                    QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=1142468.03..1142468.28 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=62052.515..62052.516 rows=3 loops=1)
   Sort Key: m.market_id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   CTE markets
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.51 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=0.006..0.010 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1142463.20..1142464.20 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=62052.502..62052.504 rows=3 loops=1)
         ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=3.25..992529.47 rows=29986746 width=8) (actual time=1.398..51289.914 rows=14297964 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (td.market_id = m.market_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on market_trades td  (cost=0.00..580208.46 rows=29986746 width=8) (actual time=0.007..21659.649 rows=29985911 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=2.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=3 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
                     ->  CTE Scan on markets m  (cost=0.00..2.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.017 rows=3 loops=1)
```

**EDIT:** Clearly the index on `market_trades.market_id` is not being used. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

With only 5 values the index isn't honing to be very selective for joining so it'll pretty much always index scan unless looking for just one value.

That query plan/anal output suggests that it thinks half the work is in matching the rows there with the CTE, could you try run the group+aggregate over the whole lot. If it is index scanning anyway you might find it faster to do that and then filter out the two you are not looking for results for.

Comment: But shouldn't the btree index on `market_trades.market_id` make it fast to do that join condition, since it doesn't have to check every row? Scanning every row in `market_trades` is not acceptable. This query should take milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: I'm not an expert on postgres so I don't know for sure, but that plan output for indicate a full scan and working to join everything before aggregating, so removing the filtering CTE join (and filtering the results after) *may* help - if you can't avoid the index scan (which you probably can't among for three space values from five, assuming the data distribution is relatively even) that will at least save a chunk of CPU work on the join operation.